# Python: How to replace string enclosed by certain characters

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to replace a certain variable name in a mathematical expression while avoid to replace in function names.

For example following replacement of `n`:

`sin(2 pi*n d)" -> "sin(2 pi*REPL d)` but not: `siREPL(2 pi*REPL d)`

My idea was to check whether the substr is enclosed by special characters (`' '` , `'('`, `'*'`, etc) at one side but I failed to put it in regex or python code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try word boundaries \b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary(`\b`)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\bn\b', 'REPL', 'sin(2 pi*n d)')
'sin(2 pi*REPL d)'
```

According to the [`re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\b`
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is
>   defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice
>   versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, ...